# Is it a good practice to add a very small number to the divisor not to deal with division by zero exception?

Tags: java, double, divide-by-zero

I want to keep my code clean and avoid unnecessary IF branches.
Is it a good practice to add a very small number to the divisor not to deal with division by zero exception? Is the below code considered a good practise? 
I know that such comparison not purely 100% accurate in this case but let's it does not matter.

```
double safeDivision(double dividend, double divisor)
{
    return (dividend + Double.MIN_VALUE)/(divisor + Double.MIN_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: No. Try `divisor = -Double.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch why should you negate it?

Comment: If the divisor is very small then you even risk numerical overflow.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Why shouldn't the caller be able to negate it? They would get a particularly inaccurate result with your method.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have not proposed any method, my question was why do you suggest `divisor = -Double.MIN_VALUE`? In addition to the other drawbacks this will also change the sign of the result

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev If the caller calls your code (as posted, the proposed method) with a value for `divisor` as specified. What is the result of `-Double.MIN_VALUE + Double.MIN_VALUE`? **Hint**: How do you deal with division by zero here?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ok, I think you are confused. This is not **my** code, this is OP's code. I am not saying OP's solution is correct, but I think I finally understand your comment. I thought you are suggesting op to try reverse sign for the additional term, while you are just saying there is a case that fails

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Correct. Sorry, yes - I thought that was your question.

Comment: Are you guys actually discussing this idea?!? WHY?  The original premise is just ... oh nevermind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can give unwanted results. How do you deal with numbers coming off an "adjusted" division by 0?

A working code is always better then a clean but potentially bugged code

Comment: As I said: a slightly  "adjusted" result does not matter in this case. The result value will be rounded and potential numeric issues are negligible

Comment: Yes but if you divide something by 0,0000000..01 you may deal with an unwanted big number, that can cause an overflow

Answer (score 17):

Why worry about this in the context of `double`?

```
System.out.println( 1.0 / 0.0);
System.out.println( 0.0 / 0.0);
System.out.println(-1.0 / 0.0);
```

yields

> Infinity
>   NaN
>   -Infinity

... which is, after all, the correct result, right? Introducing an inaccuracy will just bite you in an entirely different, unexpected way. Don't do it.

Comment: Just to be a pedant, (-)1/0 ≠ (-)Infinity, in real life maths it's undefined. Draw the graph of f(x) = (-)1/x and you'll see why.

Comment: @coudy: This isn't real life maths. This is real life Java where `(1.0 / 0.0 == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) == true`

Comment: True. I guess I'm just worried people will interpret "correct result" in an absolutistic manner as opposed to "Java says so" correct. :)

Comment: @coudy: so you're essentially saying Java is spreading "fake news"?

Comment: well, "alternative facts", really